# Keyboard is not responding

Tags: xcode, ios7, uikeyboard

I want to know about this error. Why this is happening. When I type some text, my keyboard doesn't respond . It gives this error :

```
-[UIKeyboardInputManagerClient handleError:forRequest:] will retry sending 
 generateCandidatesWithKeyboardState:candidateRange:continuation: to keyboard daemon after 
 receiving Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4097 "The operation couldn’t be completed. 
 (Cocoa error 4097.)
```

I have to wait some time so that I can type the text again. Please suggest me how can I remove this error.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: how are you making the keyboard appear?  And is the typing for a text field or is it for something else?

Comment: Yes, it is text field. And keyboard appears normally. @MichaelDautermann

Comment: it also happened with me in ios7

Comment: @SudhaTiwari Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: @TheValyreanGroup Yes, that time I was using TPKEYBOARD. So I removed that file.

Answer (score 0):

I have only seen this happen on the simulator. I was able to resolve the issue by resetting the simulator through `iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings...`

Comment: that did absolutely nothing

Answer (score -1):

Some time simulator is not working .

```
iOS Simulator -> Reset Content and Settings
```

and Click.

```
Xcode->Product->Clean ..
```

It is working for me.